# Django query list order changes in local and production

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter

```
main_filter = Consumer.objects.none()
filtering = Consumer.objects.filter(created_date=date).values().order_by('-created_date')[:1]
main_filter |= filtering
```

I just run these in a while loop by stepping down date to fetch latest record of each date.
The problem is the order of main_filter item in local system is just reverse of the order of main_filter item in production.

For Example
In local

```
main_filter = [{'Consumer': 'A'}, {'Consumer': 'B'}]
```

In production

```
main_filter = [{'Consumer': 'B'}, {'Consumer': 'A'}]
```

What is the cause of this order change?(Note: There is no change in code in local and production)

Comment: How come you are using ```.none()``` on the ```main_filter```?

Comment: @kevin We can only append a query result to a variable which is a query result.Which means we initialize a variable then in every loop we append the query result to the variable

Comment: Is the ```date``` that is passed in the ```filtering``` variable todays date? I am playing around with some cod to see what I can find for you.